# Need help to enter date from date picker

Tags: date, selenium, xpath

I have been trying to automate booking a flight on www.kayak.com/flights using Selenium webdriver in java. The issue I am having is that I am unable to enter date into the departing date and arrival date boxes, mainly because when you click in the date box, it displays a popup calendar or date picker. My many attempts to identify the xpath for the date picker itself and the date elements have not been successful as whenever I try to click on the date element in the picker, it changes focus. So, unless I can identify them somehow, I can't enter any data into them. I am sure there has to be someone out there who can help me with this dilemma. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide HTML code of that whole date component

Answer (score 0):

If you're using firebug to grab the xpath, you should see a dropdown menu right below the inspect element button. You're probably dealing with an iframe and you will need to switch focus to that frame. It should be easy to check which iframe you want if there are multiple (because the blue dotted frames will display) by passing this xpath: `//*`

You can do this several ways:

```
1) driver.switchTo().frame(name_or_id)
2) driver.switchTo().frame(index)
```

If you're still having troubles, you can always guess and check by starting with 0 and increasing it, so `driver.switchTo().frame(0)`